# Inserting rows of one table to other in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am working on an app where I need to save rows from one table to another on click of button in View. On pressing buttton, I am initally fetching rows from one table based on field passed on button click. Once the rows are fetched I insert them into a different table and then delete rows from first one. Below is the code in View

```
<div class ="sbutton">
<%= button_to "Print", { :controller => "billings", :action => "printorder", :id => @orders.first.tableno}, :method => :delete %>
</div>
```

Below is the printorder method in billings controller:

```
def printorder

        lists = List.select.where(:tablabel => "Table"+params[:id]).to_a
        lists.each do |list|
            order = Order.new(
                :orderno => list.orderno,
                :tableno => list.tableno,
                :itemname => list.itmename,
                :quantity => list.quantity,
                :amount => list.amount,

            )
            order.save
        end
        lists.delete_all
        Table.where(:tablabel => "Table"+params[:id]).update_all(:tabstatus => "available")

  end
```

In above method I fetch rows from `lists` table and update `orders` table with rows fetched for a particular table number. The table number is passed from view and I capture it in `params[:id]`. The routed file has below code for this method

```
resources :billings do
        delete :printorder, on: :member
    end
```

Problem is I am getting `tried to create Proc object without a block` in printorder method of billings controller at line `lists = List.select.where(:tablabel => "Table"+params[:id]).to_a`.

I searched a lot for this error but couldn't understand the root cause or get a solution. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: try `List.where(:tablabel => "Table"+params[:id]).to_a` ? or just `List.where(:tablabel => "Table"+params[:id]).each do |list|`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems this worked as now getting different error undefined method `delete_all' for []:Array.

Comment: your `lists` is an array and delete_all use for `ActiveRecordBase::Relation` so use `lists.clear`

Comment: @RajarshiDas  Thanks a lot. I figured this and changed it.